# Search for specific key and value from dictionary, in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
dic = {"Name":"Test1","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Test2","Age":"24"},{"Name":"Test3","Age":"21"}
```

Search for Test3 and print 21

Comment: and the question is?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want your dictionaries to be inside of a list, like this:

```
dic = [{"Name":"Test1","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Test2","Age":"24"},{"Name":"Test3","Age":"21"}]
```

Now we can find `Name` with value "Test3" and print `Age`.

```
for d in dic:
    if d["Name"] == "Test3":
        print("Age is: " + d["Age"])
```

Comment: Not necessary. Python will itself treat it as tuple

Answer (score 2):

Based on the syntax you have given, python will treat it as [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) objects. Let's see:

```
>>> dic = {"Name":"Test1","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Test2","Age":"24"},{"Name":"Test3","Age":"21"}
>>> type(dic)
<type 'tuple'>  # type as "tuple"
>>> dic  # lets print the content
    ({'Age': '23', 'Name': 'Test1'}, {'Age': '24', 'Name': 'Test2'}, {'Age': '21', 'Name': 'Test3'})
#   ^ All "dict" objects wrapped in `(...)`
```

You need to just iterate over the `tuple` (which are *similar* to [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) as far as iteration is considered), and check for the `Name` value as `Test3`. Sample code:

```
>>> for item in dic:
...     if item["Name"] == "Test3":
...         print(item["Age"])
... 
21
```

Comment: `print` should use parentheses since OP uses Python 3.